# What is the usage of flock here?

Tags: bash, flock

I am very new to bash scripting. I have read man page for flock but still I am not very clear how it works here. I'd appreciate if anyone could explain it for me.

```
if [ "$passfile" != "/etc/passwd" ]; then
  ( 
    flock -e 200
    echo "$theUsername:$thePasswd:$theUserIdd:$theGroupid:$theComment:$theHomeDirectory:$theBashDirectory">>$passFile
  ) 200>$passFile

  ( 
    flock -e 200
    echo "$theUsername:$thePasswd:0:0:0:0">>$shadowFile
  ) 200>$shadowFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo string >> file` is not atomic. So these two process were running at the same time

```
# Process 1
echo a b c >> some_file

# Process 2
echo d e f >> some_file
```

it's quite possible that the contents of `some_file` could end up with the lines intermingled. So the following is one possible result:

```
a b d e f
c
```

Obviously, that's not desirable in the case of structured files. So `flock` is used to prevent two processes from modifying the file at the same time.

It only works if *both* processes use `flock`. So the assumption is that the script using `flock` is the only script which modifies the password and shadow files, or at least the every script which modifies those files uses the same mechanism.

It's necessary to do this because it's quite possible that two users would independently attempt to run the script without co-ordination, and so they might do so at exactly the same time.